Rolling sum of a column by sym in KDB table
Trying to reverse engineer a line of qsql code or write a function to get the result of the rcc column in the below table. I know it's the rolling creditNettingValue by sym, however struggling with the logic when sym s3 adds and subtracts between rows 7 and 9.
I can't get the last row in my solution to add up to 14902245.
Any help really appreciated.
t:flip (`time`date`sym`creditNettingValue`rcc)!(20:55:02.761 20:55:02.788 20:55:07.795 20:55:07.814 21:11:28.196 21:26:20.012 22:25:58.292 03:20:37.019 03:35:38.739 03:40:40.805 03:57:40.102 04:21:12.093 04:21:13.130 04:21:18.140 04:21:18.156 04:21:23.167 04:21:24.179 04:22:03.209 04:22:53.123 05:20:40.271;2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01 2024.10.01;`s1`s1`s1`s1`s2`s2`s3`s4`s3`s3`s2`s4`s4`s4`s4`s4`s4`s4`s4`s3;-1000000j, -1000000j, -1000000j, -1000000j, 634279j, 634024j, 692808j, 1000000j, -690593j, -690423j, 631056j, 1000000j, 1000000j, 1000000j, 1000000j, 1000000j, 1000000j, 1000000j, 1000000j, 691094j;1000000j, 2000000j, 3000000j, 4000000j, 4634279j, 5268303j, 5961111j, 6961111j, 6270518j, 6956511j, 7587567j, 8587567j, 9587567j, 10587567j, 11587567j, 12587567j, 13587567j, 14587567j, 15587567j, 14902245j)

UPDATE
I found a (very messy) solution below
I'm attempting to calculate credit consumption, the sign is ignored when summing against other syms pairs, but as the credit goes positive/negative for each sym it must be adjusted along the way (Apologies for the poor explanation, hopefully my solution below makes it a bit more clear)
There is obviously a much more simple way to do this - If anyone can point me to a cleaner solution I would be very greatful.
t:update creditNettingBreakdown:abs sums each '{x,'enlist y} scan creditNettingValue by sym from t
t:update nettingBySym:last each last each {x-prev x} ''[creditNettingBreakdown] from t
//my logic has removed the first value of each creditNetting, need to replace in table and calculate the total
t:update rcc_calc:sums nettingBySym from t lj `time`sym xkey select time,sym,nettingBySym:abs creditNettingValue from t where rcc=(first;rcc) fby sym 
//check rcc=rcc_calc
update d_rcc:deltas'[rcc;rcc_calc] from t


show 'your solution' pls

Have updated my answer based on extra info.

You solution can be simplified to:
/Avoid extra enlisting
t:update creditNettingBreakdown:abs sums each {x,y} scan creditNettingValue by sym from t
/Keep the initial value with a type check
t:update nettingBySym:{$[-7h=type x;x;last x-prev x]} each creditNettingBreakdown from t
t:update rcc_calc:sums nettingBySym from t

Also your query:
select time,sym,nettingBySym:abs creditNettingValue from t where rcc=(first;rcc) fby sym


Is using rcc to create it's own replacement which cannot be used as a solution
If the first value of rcc is repeated you will get more than one result

If you want to do this type of fby use i=(first;i) fby

as per @rianoc but ordered by time
definitely some crucial information missing in order to unravel.
update eq:abs[creditNettingValue]=abs d_rcc from update d_rcc:deltas rcc from asc t
time         date       sym creditNettingValue rcc      d_rcc     eq
--------------------------------------------------------------------
03:20:37.019 2024.10.01 s4  1000000            6961111  6961111   0 
03:35:38.739 2024.10.01 s3  -690593            6270518  -690593   1 
03:40:40.805 2024.10.01 s3  -690423            6956511  685993    0 
03:57:40.102 2024.10.01 s2  631056             7587567  631056    1 
04:21:12.093 2024.10.01 s4  1000000            8587567  1000000   1 
04:21:13.130 2024.10.01 s4  1000000            9587567  1000000   1 
04:21:18.140 2024.10.01 s4  1000000            10587567 1000000   1 
04:21:18.156 2024.10.01 s4  1000000            11587567 1000000   1 
04:21:23.167 2024.10.01 s4  1000000            12587567 1000000   1 
04:21:24.179 2024.10.01 s4  1000000            13587567 1000000   1 
04:22:03.209 2024.10.01 s4  1000000            14587567 1000000   1 
04:22:53.123 2024.10.01 s4  1000000            15587567 1000000   1 
05:20:40.271 2024.10.01 s3  691094             14902245 -685322   0 
20:55:02.761 2024.10.01 s1  -1000000           1000000  -13902245 0 
20:55:02.788 2024.10.01 s1  -1000000           2000000  1000000   1 
20:55:07.795 2024.10.01 s1  -1000000           3000000  1000000   1 
20:55:07.814 2024.10.01 s1  -1000000           4000000  1000000   1 
21:11:28.196 2024.10.01 s2  634279             4634279  634279    1 
21:26:20.012 2024.10.01 s2  634024             5268303  634024    1 
22:25:58.292 2024.10.01 s3  692808             5961111  692808    1 


